# OAuth Code Authorization grant with PKCE but for app, not user

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3, pkce

The OAuth2 spec defines a Client Credential grant for machine-to-machine authorization, where a user isn't involved. Identity is confirmed via a client secret. This isn't appropriate for a native client, such as a mobile application, because stored client secrets can't be guaranteed.

Mobile apps can make use of the OAuth Code Authorization grant plus Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE), which allows a dynamically generated secret. This is great if you need user authorization/authentication.

However, what if you just need to protect your API's resources so that only your mobile app can use it, but you don't track users? That is, I'd like to get an access token for my application, instead of for a user.

It seems like Code Authorization + PKCE would work great, if only both the login and consent screens could be disabled. Just return the auth code. I was hoping to find a way to do this in IdentityServer3, but haven't.

Is there a configuration or flow that allows this? Or am I making a security mistake?

EDIT
It further seems to me that using PKCE *should* allow for a flow with two backchannel calls, one to the authorize endpoint, the other to the token endpoint. Essentially, Code Authorization without the browser redirection. I know such a flow isn't in the spec, but am I right? Regardless, the question remains, how to authorize a mobile app using its own account, not a user's?

Comment: Hi @charles-flatt, did you find an answer? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Nope, never did.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same thing. Please provide any guidance if you find how to do it since.